# Array stacking/ concatenation error in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two arrays: a and b, where

```
a.shape
(1460,10)
b.shape
(1460,)
```

I tried using hstack and concatenate as:

```
np.hstack((a,b)) 
c=np.concatenate(a,b,0)
```

I am stuck with the error

```
 ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Please guide me for concatenation and generating array c with dimensions 1460 x 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
b = np.expand_dims( b,axis=1 )
```

then

```
np.hstack((a,b))
```

or

```
np.concatenate( (a,b) , axis=1)
```

will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

`np.c_[a, b]` concatenates along the last axis.
Per [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html),

> ... arrays will be stacked along their last axis after
>   being upgraded to at least 2-D with 1's post-pended to the shape

Since `b` has shape `(1460,)` its shape gets upgraded to `(1460, 1)` before concatenation along the last axis.

---

```
In [26]: c = np.c_[a,b]

In [27]: c.shape
Out[27]: (1460, 11)
```

Comment: How can I store this array? Assignment does not work: it says "TypeError: 'CClass' object is not callable"

Comment: @optimist: Note that `np.c_` is followed by brackets `[...]` rather than paretheses `(...)`. The error `'CClass' object is not callable` is saying that `np.c_` can not be called, which is what happens when it is followed by parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic operation that works is:

```
np.concatenate((a,b[:,None]),axis=1)
```

The `[:,None]` bit turns `b` into a `(1060,1)` array.  Now the 1st dimensions of both arrays match, and you can easily concatenate on the 2nd.

There a many ways of adding the 2nd dimension to `b`, such as `reshape` and `expanddims`.  `hstack` uses `atleast_1d` which does not help in this case.  `atleast_2d` adds the `None` on the wrong side.  I strongly advocate learning the `[:,None]` syntax.

Once the arrays are both 2d and match on the correct dimensions, concatenation is easy.